# Google Cloud TPU: capture_tpu_profile: No trace event is collected after N attempt(s)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

While following [Cloud TPU profiling guide](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools) and [Bert FineTuning](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert-2.x?cloudshell=false), I got error when creating Profile data.
Scalars and Graphs in TensorBoards are working well.

Is there anything I'm missing?

### Configurations

Zone: us-central1-a(Both for Storage and TPU)
TPU Type: v3-8
TPU software version: tpu-vm-tf-2.7.0
TPU Architecture: TPU VM

### Error log

##### Using CLI

(Run when training is process)

```
> capture_tpu_profile --tpu=bert-tpu --logdir=${MODEL_DIR} --duration_ms=3000

2022-01-20 06:34:29.301737: I tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_initializer_helper.cc:68] libtpu.so already in used by another process. Not attempting to load libtpu.so in this process.
2022-01-20 06:34:29.301787: I tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_api_dlsym_initializer.cc:116] Libtpu path is: libtpu.so
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogle() is written to STDERR
I0120 06:34:29.324573   67944 tpu_initializer_helper.cc:68] libtpu.so already in used by another process. Not attempting to load libtpu.so in this process.
2022-01-20 06:34:29.336671: I tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_initializer_helper.cc:68] libtpu.so already in used by another process. Not attempting to load libtpu.so in this process.
2022-01-20 06:34:31.607899: I tensorflow/stream_executor/tpu/tpu_platform_interface.cc:77] No TPU platform registered. Waiting 1 second and trying again... (4 tries left)
2022-01-20 06:34:32.608170: I tensorflow/stream_executor/tpu/tpu_platform_interface.cc:77] No TPU platform registered. Waiting 1 second and trying again... (3 tries left)
2022-01-20 06:34:33.608461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/tpu/tpu_platform_interface.cc:77] No TPU platform registered. Waiting 1 second and trying again... (2 tries left)
2022-01-20 06:34:34.608757: I tensorflow/stream_executor/tpu/tpu_platform_interface.cc:77] No TPU platform registered. Waiting 1 second and trying again... (1 tries left)
2022-01-20 06:34:35.609050: I tensorflow/stream_executor/tpu/tpu_platform_interface.cc:74] No TPU platform found.
TensorFlow version 2.7.0 detected
Welcome to the Cloud TPU Profiler v2.4.0
I0120 06:34:35.628104 140127504198720 discovery.py:280] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tpu/v1/rest
I0120 06:34:35.709828 140127504198720 discovery.py:911] URL being requested: GET https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/elsa-270714/locations/us-central1-a/nodes/bert-tpu?alt=json
I0120 06:34:35.710047 140127504198720 transport.py:157] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
I0120 06:34:35.710207 140127504198720 client.py:777] Refreshing access_token
I0120 06:34:35.806093 140127504198720 discovery.py:280] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tpu/v1/rest
I0120 06:34:35.838788 140127504198720 discovery.py:911] URL being requested: GET https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/elsa-270714/locations/us-central1-a/nodes/bert-tpu?alt=json
I0120 06:34:35.838929 140127504198720 transport.py:157] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
I0120 06:34:35.839013 140127504198720 client.py:777] Refreshing access_token
Starting to trace for 3000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 2
No trace event is collected. Automatically retrying.

Starting to trace for 3000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 1
No trace event is collected. Automatically retrying.

Starting to trace for 3000 ms. Remaining attempt(s): 0
No trace event is collected after 3 attempt(s). Perhaps, you want to try again (with more attempts?).
Tip: increase number of attempts with --num_tracing_attempts.
```

##### Using TensorBoard

(TPU name: bert-tpu)
[image]

### Packages

```
> pip3 list

Package                           Version
--------------------------------- --------------------
absl-py                           0.12.0
anyio                             3.5.0
argon2-cffi                       21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings              21.2.0
asttokens                         2.0.5
astunparse                        1.6.3
attrs                             19.3.0
Automat                           0.8.0
Babel                             2.9.1
backcall                          0.2.0
backports.entry-points-selectable 1.1.1
black                             21.12b0
bleach                            4.1.0
blinker                           1.4
cachetools                        4.2.4
certifi                           2021.10.8
cffi                              1.15.0
chardet                           3.0.4
charset-normalizer                2.0.7
click                             8.0.3
cloud-init                        21.4
cloud-tpu-client                  0.10
cloud-tpu-profiler                2.4.0
colorama                          0.4.3
command-not-found                 0.3
configobj                         5.0.6
constantly                        15.1.0
cryptography                      2.8
cycler                            0.11.0
Cython                            0.29.24
dbus-python                       1.2.16
debugpy                           1.5.1
decorator                         5.1.1
defusedxml                        0.7.1
dill                              0.3.4
distlib                           0.3.3
distro                            1.4.0
distro-info                       0.23ubuntu1
dm-tree                           0.1.6
entrypoints                       0.3
executing                         0.8.2
filelock                          3.4.0
flatbuffers                       2.0
fonttools                         4.28.5
future                            0.18.2
gast                              0.4.0
gin-config                        0.5.0
google-api-core                   1.31.4
google-api-python-client          1.8.0
google-auth                       1.35.0
google-auth-httplib2              0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib              0.4.6
google-pasta                      0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos          1.53.0
grpcio                            1.42.0
gviz-api                          1.10.0
h5py                              3.6.0
httplib2                          0.20.2
hyperlink                         19.0.0
idna                              3.3
importlib-metadata                4.8.2
importlib-resources               5.4.0
incremental                       16.10.1
intel-openmp                      2021.4.0
ipykernel                         6.7.0
ipython                           8.0.0
ipython-genutils                  0.2.0
jax                               0.2.25
jaxlib                            0.1.74
jedi                              0.18.1
Jinja2                            2.10.1
joblib                            1.1.0
json5                             0.9.6
jsonpatch                         1.22
jsonpointer                       2.0
jsonschema                        3.2.0
jupyter-client                    7.1.1
jupyter-core                      4.9.1
jupyter-server                    1.13.3
jupyterlab                        3.2.8
jupyterlab-pygments               0.1.2
jupyterlab-server                 2.10.3
kaggle                            1.5.12
keras                             2.7.0
Keras-Applications                1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing               1.1.2
keyring                           18.0.1
kiwisolver                        1.3.2
language-selector                 0.1
launchpadlib                      1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient                0.14.2
lazr.uri                          1.0.3
libclang                          12.0.0
Markdown                          3.3.6
MarkupSafe                        1.1.0
matplotlib                        3.5.1
matplotlib-inline                 0.1.3
mistune                           0.8.4
mkl                               2021.4.0
mkl-include                       2021.4.0
mock                              4.0.3
more-itertools                    4.2.0
mypy-extensions                   0.4.3
nbclassic                         0.3.5
nbclient                          0.5.10
nbconvert                         6.4.0
nbformat                          5.1.3
nest-asyncio                      1.5.4
netifaces                         0.10.4
notebook                          6.4.7
numpy                             1.18.5
oauth2client                      4.1.3
oauthlib                          3.1.0
opencv-python-headless            4.5.5.62
opt-einsum                        3.3.0
packaging                         21.3
pandas                            1.3.5
pandocfilters                     1.5.0
parso                             0.8.3
pathspec                          0.9.0
pexpect                           4.6.0
pickleshare                       0.7.5
Pillow                            8.4.0
pip                               21.3.1
platformdirs                      2.4.0
portalocker                       2.3.2
prometheus-client                 0.12.0
promise                           2.3
prompt-toolkit                    3.0.24
protobuf                          3.19.1
psutil                            5.9.0
ptyprocess                        0.7.0
pure-eval                         0.2.1
py-cpuinfo                        8.0.0
pyasn1                            0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                    0.2.8
pycocotools                       2.0.4
pycparser                         2.21
Pygments                          2.11.2
PyGObject                         3.36.0
PyHamcrest                        1.9.0
PyJWT                             1.7.1
pymacaroons                       0.13.0
PyNaCl                            1.3.0
pyOpenSSL                         19.0.0
pyparsing                         3.0.6
pyrsistent                        0.15.5
pyserial                          3.4
python-apt                        2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.6
python-dateutil                   2.8.2
python-debian                     0.1.36ubuntu1
python-slugify                    5.0.2
pytz                              2021.3
PyYAML                            5.4.1
pyzmq                             22.3.0
regex                             2022.1.18
requests                          2.26.0
requests-oauthlib                 1.3.0
requests-unixsocket               0.2.0
rsa                               4.7.2
sacrebleu                         2.0.0
scikit-learn                      1.0.2
scipy                             1.7.2
SecretStorage                     2.3.1
Send2Trash                        1.8.0
sentencepiece                     0.1.96
seqeval                           1.2.2
service-identity                  18.1.0
setuptools                        59.2.0
simplejson                        3.16.0
six                               1.16.0
sniffio                           1.2.0
sos                               4.1
ssh-import-id                     5.10
stack-data                        0.1.4
systemd-python                    234
tabulate                          0.8.9
tbb                               2021.4.0
tensorboard                       2.7.0
tensorboard-data-server           0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-profile        2.5.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit            1.8.0
tensorflow                        2.7.0
tensorflow-addons                 0.15.0
tensorflow-datasets               4.4.0
tensorflow-estimator              2.7.0
tensorflow-hub                    0.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem      0.22.0
tensorflow-metadata               1.5.0
tensorflow-model-optimization     0.7.0
tensorflow-text                   2.7.0rc1
termcolor                         1.1.0
terminado                         0.12.1
testpath                          0.5.0
text-unidecode                    1.3
tf-slim                           1.1.0
threadpoolctl                     3.0.0
tomli                             1.2.3
torch                             1.11.0a0+git4635f57
torch-xla                         1.11+73a3937
torchvision                       0.12.0a0+59baae9
tornado                           6.1
tqdm                              4.62.3
traitlets                         5.1.1
Twisted                           18.9.0
typeguard                         2.13.3
typing_extensions                 4.0.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools            27.4
ufw                               0.36
unattended-upgrades               0.1
uritemplate                       3.0.1
urllib3                           1.26.7
virtualenv                        20.10.0
wadllib                           1.3.3
wcwidth                           0.2.5
webencodings                      0.5.1
websocket-client                  1.2.3
Werkzeug                          2.0.2
wheel                             0.34.2
wrapt                             1.13.3
zipp                              3.7.0
zope.interface                    4.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `capture_tpu_profile` doesn't work with TPU VM.

- If you're using TF2/Keras, one very accessible way is to use the [TensorBoard Callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard) and set `profile_batch=1` for instance. This would work for v3-8 but unfortunately wouldn't work for >v3-8.
- Alternatively, you can use [`tf.profiler.experimental.start(...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental/start) and [`tf.profiler.experimental.stop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental/stop) which is what the TensorBoard callback uses under the hood.
- If you're using >v3-8 (for instance v3-32) you can use [`tf.profiler.experimental.client.trace()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental/client/trace) where `service_addr` is accessible from `TPUClusterResolver`'s [`get_master()` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/cluster_resolver/TPUClusterResolver#get_master).